# Encrypt file list when creating 7zip archive on command line

Tags: archive, 7z

When creating a 7zip archive with `file-roller`, there is a checkbox labeled "Encrypt the file list too". And it seems to work as you cannot see the file list when opening an archive created with this checkbox ticked until you enter the password (which you are immediately prompted for when opening the archive), whereas you can see the file list and only are prompted the enter the password upon trying to access the files in the archive.

From `7zip`'s man page, I know that one can create an encrypted archive by passing the `p` switch. But the file lists of those archives aren't encrypted.

How do I encrypt the file list of a 7zip archive when creating it from the command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the manual page for `7z`:

```
   -mhe=on|off
          7z format only : enables or disables archive header encryption (Default : off)
```